# Cyrillic (windows-1251) jQuery ajax post error

Tags: php, ajax, database, post

I have a problem when I try to send Cyrillic (Russian) chars to a database (CP 1251 col). I try to send this: "Фамилия, Имя", but in the database it appears as "Р¤Р°РјРёР»РёСЏ, РРјСЏ". It's interesting that when I send the same data without Ajax (the same form, but with a simple request) it works all right. So, it is not a db connect problem and so on... The problem is in my Ajax script.
I hope you'll help. Thanks.

Here is my code:

JS file:

```
$(function() {
  $('.error').hide();
  function emailCorect(adresaEmail) {
    var shablon = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
    return shablon.test(adresaEmail);
  };

  $("#submit_btn").click(function() {
    // validate and process form
    // first hide any error messages
    $('.error').hide();
    var name = $("input#name").val();
    var email = $("input#email").val();
    var txt = $("#txt").val();
    if(name == "" || email == "" || !emailCorect(email) || txt == "") {
      if (name == "") {
        $("#name_error").show();
        $("input#name").focus();
      }
      if (email == "") {
        $("#email_error").show();
        $("input#email").focus();
      }
      if(!emailCorect(email)) {
        // in case it's not a valid e-mail-ul
        $("#email_error").show();
        $("input#email").focus();
      }
      if (txt == "") {
        $("#txt_error").show();
        $("#txt").focus();
      }
      return false;
    }
    var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&txt=' + txt;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "./../ajax/opinii.php",
      data: dataString,
      success: function() {
        $('#adauga').html("<div id='ajax_succes_txt'></div>");
        $('#ajax_succes_txt').fadeIn(1500, function() {
          $('#ajax_succes_txt').html("<img src='../juststy/images/check.png' /><br />").append("Opinia dvs. a fost publicat&#259;.<br /><span style='font-size: 10px; color:red;'><b>aten&#355;ie:</b> dac&#259; vei publica opinii &icirc;ntr-un interval scurt de timp, acestea nu vor fi publicate.");
        });
        $('#render').load("./../inc/1/");
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

PHP file:

```
<?php
  require_once("./../core/system.php");
  dbconnect();
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $txt = $_POST['txt'];
  $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO opinii(name,mail,txt,ip,data) VALUES(
    ".sqlesc($name).",".sqlesc($email).",".sqlesc($txt).",".
    sqlesc($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']).",".sqlesc(get_time()).")")
    or die(mysql_error());
  if($query){echo "OK"; }?>
```

PHP CONNECT FUNCTION (ADDED at 13:15 15-07-2012)

```
function dbconnect($mode = "load")
{
    global $mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $mysql_db;

    $link = @mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass);

    if (!@mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass)) 
    {
        die('A intervenit o eroare la conectarea cu baza de date. Dac&#259; e&#351;ti un utilizator, revino mai t&acirc;rziu.');
    }

    mysql_select_db($mysql_db) or die('A intervenit o eroare la selectarea bazei de date. Dac&#259; e&#351;ti un utilizator, revino mai t&acirc;rziu.');

    switch($mode) {
        case "load":    
            mysql_query("SET NAMES cp1251");
            break;
        case "insert":
            mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: It is 2012, a time to start using Unicode. PS: giving `shablon` and `adresaEmail` names to variables is a really terrible practice

Comment: AJAX works only with utf-8 encoding. So as **zerkms** said it's time to start using it. Good luck.

Comment: You can try specifying encoding in your `$.ajax` call using parameter `contentTypeString: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=...'` Try playing with the charset to possibly get what you need.  Ideally, of course, you'll move everything to UTF-8, including your database, but I appreciate that this may not always be under your control.

Comment: This is not true. You can specify any encoding with AJAX by explicitly specifying `content-type` header - either directly (`xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=...")`) or by passing an extra parameter to the jquery call (`contentTypeString: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=...'`)

Comment: @Stano yeee737's statement that ajax only works with utf-8 is wrong.  This is what I described in my comment.  You are simply suggesting another solution to the OP's issue.

Comment: @AleksG Ok, thanks Aleks, it was my mistake. So the alternative solution is: `var dataString = 'name='+ encodeURI(name) + '&email=' + email + '&txt=' + encodeURI(txt); ... $name = urldecode($_POST['name']); $txt = urldecode($_POST['txt']);`

Comment: @Stano sounds about right, but you should test it.

Comment: @AleksG Tested it with [this script](http://pastebin.com/U3B1q5sc), seems to work good.

Comment: OK, guys, i tried to change my collations, everything to UTF-8 and UTF8_UNICODE_CI. Now, script insert the right chars in database, but when i read them from mysql database it gives wrong characters. It is interesting that if i read from db and use mysql_query("SET NAMES cp1251"); it goes OK. So, i edited my php connection to db something like that:, and it works, but it a little strange way to solve this problem, so maybe you'll help me to solve another way :| The best solution is to help me set normally everything to UTF8 Unicode. I'll be glad. Thx

Comment: thanks, but doesn't work. Look, it's a my own source i am developing, so, there is no problems to loose information, and so on... Can someone give me a simple source that works perfectly on UTF8-Unicode? This is what i need, thank you.

Comment: I think this would be the easiest way to solve my problems :)